# Loading modules at runtime from functions

Tags: python

I would like to load modules at runtime.

If I do it like this it works:

```
a = __import__('datetime',globals(),locals(),[],-1)

for e in a.__dict__:
    if not e.startswith("__"):
        globals()[e] = a.__dict__[e]
```

But if I try to do this it doesn't work:

```
def module_loader(modname,g,l):
    a = __import__(modname,g(),l(),[],-1)

    for e in a.__dict__:
        if not e.startswith("__"):
            g()[e] = a.__dict__[e]


module_loader('datetime',globals,locals)
```

Any help?

Comment: In your second example, `a`  is local to `module_loader`. You should thus get a `NameError` when accessing `a.__dict__` in the `for`-loop. Futhermore, `module_loader` expects three arguments but receives only one.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying attention when writing my problem, I am a little bit frustrated :)

Comment: Now you have an indentation-error in your second example (after the `if`-statement). If you are frustrated, take 2 Minutes to calm down and then present a working example to illustrate the problem. This is the fastest way to get a solution.

Comment: Here it is, stackoverflow is giving me wrong formatting on paste. Here is working version: http://pastebin.com/3aQBVPZn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet above works for me if I call it as

```
module_loader('datetime', globals, locals)
```

Comment: What does it mean it works, beause it doesn't import it into global namespace.

Comment: It does, Once I call the above function, I can use any of the objects defined inside datetime. For e.g. MINYEAR, MAXYEAR, date etc.

Comment: Here is my running: http://pastebin.com/QR8YPNTs I cannot get it to global namespace.

Comment: Can you put your running to pastebin, tnx.

Comment: Its the scope thats causing the problem. You are calling it from outside of the script and the globals definition is not available once the script is parsed. Here is a snippet (Ive added print globals() to tst.py) so that you see that the objects are infact added to globals when the call is made. http://pastebin.com/CBEgQgBG

Comment: On the other hand, if I try this completely in a REPL, this is what I have: http://pastebin.com/h2ty9uF6

Answer (score 0):

```
def module_loader(modname,g,l):
    a = __import__(modname,g(),l(),[],-1)

    for e in a.__dict__:
        if not e.startswith("__"):
            g()[e] = a.__dict__[e]

module_loader('datetime', globals, locals)
```